# Silverstripe: Member relation many many null, form front end

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe, member

**Fatal error: Call to a member function Services() on null**

```
class MemberProfileViewer extends Page_Controller {

    // ...

    public function Servizi() {
        $source = null;
        if ($id = (int)$this->urlParams['ID']) {
            $member = Member::get()->byID($id);
            if ($member instanceof Member) {
                return $source = $member->Services()->map('Title','Title');
            }
        } 

        if (is_null($id)) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }

        if (is_null($source)) {
            return $this->httpError(404);
        } 

    }

    public function form() {

        $fields = new FieldList(
            CheckboxSetField::create(
                $name = "ServiceID",
                $title = "Select",
                $source = $this->Servizi()
            ),
        )

        $actions = FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('form', 'Send')
                    ->setUseButtonTag(true)
                    ->addExtraClass('btn btn-primary')
        );

        $validator = new RequiredFields('ServiceID');

        $form = new Form($this, 'form', $fields, $actions, $validator);
        $form->setFormMethod('POST', true);
        return $form;
    }

    public function doform($data, $form) {
        $form->sessionMessage(
            "Thank you, you will be contacted as soon as possible by our consultant.", 'good'
        );

        $submission = new RequestForm();
        $form->saveInto($submission);
        $submission->write();

        return $this->redirectBack();

    }

}
```

> **is always null** 
>  I do not know how to solve

### Yes, this has solved the problem!

```
class MemberProfileViewer extends Page_Controller {

    // ...

    public function currentPageID() {
        $id = 0;
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if(is_numeric($request->requestVar('ID')))  {
            $id = $request->requestVar('ID');
        } elseif (is_numeric($request->param('ID'))) {
            $id = $request->param('ID');
        }

        $id = (int)$id;
        return $id;
    }

    public function Servizi() {
        $source = null;
        if ($id = $this->currentPageID()) {
            Session::set('ID', $id);
            return $source = Member::get()->byID($id)->Services()->map('Title','Title')->toArray();
        } elseif (is_null($source)) {
           return $source = Member::get()->byID(Session::get('ID'))->Services()->map('Title','Title')->toArray();
        } 

    }

    public function form() {

        $fields = new FieldList(
            CheckboxSetField::create(
                $name = "Service",
                $title = "Select",
                $source = $this->Servizi()
            ),
        )

        $actions = FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('form', 'Send')
                    ->setUseButtonTag(true)
                    ->addExtraClass('btn btn-primary')
        );

        $validator = new RequiredFields('Service');

        $form = new Form($this, 'form', $fields, $actions, $validator);
        $form->setFormMethod('POST', true);

        $data = Session::get("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data");
        return $data ? $form->loadDataFrom($data) : $form;
    }

    public function doform($data, $form) {
        Session::set("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data", $data);

        $submission = new RequestForm();
        $form->saveInto($submission);
        $submission->write();

        $form->sessionMessage(
            "Thank you, you will be contacted as soon as possible by our consultant.", 'good'
        );

        Session::clear("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data");
        return $this->redirectBack();

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the value of `$this->urlParams['ID']`? You should add some error handling in case the member isn't found, before you try to use it

Comment: You need to code more defensively dude, you can't just expect to get an instance of Member all the time. What if there is no member with that ID? What if there is no 'ID' set on the urlParams array?

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
$source = null;
if ($id = $this->urlParams['ID']) {
    $member = Member::get()->byId($id);
    if ($member instanceof Member) {
        $source = $member->Services()->map('Title','Title');
    }
}

if (is_null($source)) {
    //don't show that field, show a LiteralField with an error maybe
} else {
    //show your field with $source
}
```

Comment: Hi @BenDubuisson, A step forward thanks! But message validation **Please select a value within the list provided. {value} is not a valid option**
I tried with a manual id and it works, because in dynamic no?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: Example: **byId(7)** works | byId($id) return Please select a value within the list provided. value is not a valid option.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you're talking about. Where do these messages come from??

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably because of this line

```
$fields = new FieldList(
    CheckboxSetField::create(
        $name = "ServiceID",
        $title = "Select",
        $source = $this->Servizi() // <--
    ),
)
```

Your method `Servizi()` depends on some routing (you try to get a Member ID from the URL). The method does not **always** return a good map for your CheckboxSetField. If you don't have a route for your `Servizi()` method, you probably don't want to redirect or return a http error.

Now I don't know how you got your Member ID so that is up to you how you will get that. But you will be able to fix it like this.

```
public function servizi($memberId = 0)
{
    $array = [];

    if(! $memberId && ! ($memberId = Member::currentUserID())) // check current logged in Member
        return $array;

    if(! $member = Member::get()->byID($memberId))
        return $array;

    return $member->Services()->map('Title','Title');
}
```

The code above is not tested.

Comment: It should be that the relationship does not belong to user logged. Get a Member ID from the URL, or otherwise

Comment: Then figure out a way to give the MemberID in the parameters of the `servizi` method. You do not provide enough information to help you on that matter. Just make sure the method returns an array or map and not a response object...

Comment: I need to ID of the page to show the relationship of the options that are available in form  automatically, attention not currentUserID.  I don't know how to do that. By using the values to submit $this->get Request()->param('ID')  returns null. Inserting a number ->byId(1) works, How do I make  get form Page user ID parameter.  thank you so much @FatalError